# Allocating observations to test whether two expected values are equal$\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}=\Delta\neq 0?$

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Question:

> Suppose that you wish to test the hypothesis $H_{0}:\mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$ versus $H_{1}:\mu_{1}\neq \mu_{2}$,where both variances $\sigma^2_{1}$ and $\sigma^2_{2}$ are know ,A tatal of $n_{1}+n_{2}=N$ observations can be taken.How should these observations be allocated to the two populations to maximize the probability that $H_{0}$ will be rejected if $H_{1}$ is true and $\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}=\Delta\neq 0?$

This is my homework,and I can't find this solution,  and I have to turn it in in on Wednesday,so I hope someone can help ,If help me to answer,

I would be very grateful to you

because this homewor is very important to me!

maybe this problem is not easy?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please say how you got stuck.

Comment: Hello,I can't how to use this condition:$n_{1}+n_{2}=N$,can you help me,Thank you

Comment: You want ot maximize the power of the test or equivalently you want to minimize the Type II error by the choise of $n_1$, $n_2$. Can you calculate Type II errors?

Comment: Hello,I can't,sorry.can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $μ_1-μ_2=Δ$ you have that $$Z'=\frac{\bar x_1-\bar x_2-Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}\sim \mathrm N(0,1)$$ But under the null hypothesis we have that also $$Z=\frac{\bar x_1-\bar x_2-0}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}\sim \mathrm N(0,1)$$ Since $$Z=\frac{\bar x_1-\bar x_2-0\pm Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}=\frac{\bar x_1-\bar x_2-Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}+\frac{Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}=Z'+\frac{Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}$$ we have that $$Z=Z'+δ$$ where $δ=\frac{Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}$. Thus we want to maximize by the choice of $n_1, n_2$ the probability $$\begin{align*}P\left(\text{ Accept }H_1| H_1 \text{ is true }\right)&=P\left(|Z|>z_{α/2}|μ_1-μ_2=Δ\right)=P\left(\left|Z'+δ\right|>z_{α/2}\right) =\\ \\&=\ldots=1-\left[Φ\left(z_{α/2}-δ\right)-Φ(-z_{α/2}-δ)\right]=\\&=2-Φ(z_{α/2}-δ)-Φ(z_{α/2}+δ)\end{align*}$$ According to the above calculations, this is equivalent to minimizing the term $$Φ(z_{α/2}-δ)+Φ(z_{α/2}+δ)$$ with respect to $δ$ (which depends on the choice of $n_1,n_2$). Due to the shape of the normal curve (draw a shape) the above probability is minimized when $δ$ is maximized, which leads to the conclusion that we want to maximize with the choice of $n_1$ and $n_2$ the term $$δ=\frac{Δ}{\sqrt{\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}}}$$ under the constraint $n_1+n_2=N$. This is (again) equivalent to minimizing the term $$\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}$$ subject to $n_1+n_2=N$, where $σ_1^2, σ_2^2$ are known constants. This is a non-linear programm which can be solved by the use of the [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). That is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial n_1}\left(\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}+λ(n_1+n_2-N)\right)=-\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1^2}+λ$$ and similarly $$\frac{\partial}{\partial n_2}\left(\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{σ^2_2}{n_2}+λ(n_1+n_2-N)\right)=-\frac{σ_2^2}{n_2^2}+λ$$ Setting the partial derivatives equal to zero and solving for $λ$ we have that $$λ=\frac{σ_1^2}{n_1^2}=\frac{σ_2^2}{n_2^2}$$ which gives that $$n_1^2=\frac{σ_1^2}{σ_2^2}n_2^2$$ or equivalently that $$n_2=\frac{σ_2}{σ_1}n_1$$ Substituting in the initial constraint, we find that $$n_1+\frac{σ_2}{σ_1}n_1=N$$ which gives $$n_1=\frac{N}{1+\frac{σ_2}{σ_1}}=\frac{σ_1Ν}{σ_1+σ_2}$$ Substituting the value of $n_1$ in the relation between $n_1$ and $n_2$ we find finally that $$n_2=\frac{σ_2}{σ_1}\cdot\frac{σ_1Ν}{σ_1+σ_2}=\frac{σ_2N}{σ_1+σ_2}$$ So, the optimal allocation of the disposable observations is $$n_1=\frac{σ_1}{σ_1+σ_2}N \qquad \text{ and } \qquad n_2=\frac{σ_2}{σ_1+σ_2}N$$ Obviously, since $n_1,n_2$ are integers, the values of $n_1$ and $n_2$ that will result from the above formulas should be rounded to the nearest integers.